# Javascript regex to make sure that string matches format x:y

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a string which has two numbers, both can be between 1 and 3 digits, and will have a colon in between. Here are some examples:

"1:1"
"1:12"
"12:1"
"123:12"

Also, the given string may also be invalid, and I need to detect if it is. My attempts so far to make sure the string is valid have looked like this: `.match(/[1-9]\:[1-9]/);`. But then I noticed that this wont work if a string such as this is inputted: `"characters12:4characters"`. How would I go about validating the string to make sure it is in the format x:y?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

> Edit: numbers which contain 0 at the beginning is valid, but may not be given.

Comment: Is `10:100` valid? I understand `010:100` is not, right?

Comment: Yes, x can be 1 to 3 digits, same for y. Then the string should be in the format `x:y`

Comment: `010:100` is also valid.

Comment: Then you need `/^\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}$/`

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm! Post it as an answer so I can accept

Comment: `[1-9]` doesn't allow zeroes, is that intentional?

Comment: Oh, thats another mistake which I probably missed in my code... But the correct solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\d{1,3}:\d{1,3}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/muPpIU/1)

**Details**

- `^` - [start of a string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits (`\d` is a [shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) that matches any digit (it can also be written as a `[0-9]` character class) and `{1,3}` is a [limited quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that matches1 to 3 consecutive occurrences of the quantified subpattern)
- `:` - a colon
- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `$` - [end of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).